# Report Builder Data Sources Do Not Change in Catalog Table

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2008

I am trying to extract the connection string for MS SSRS reports from the Report Server Catalog table. This is straightforward enough but if I change the Data Source in Report Builder, the change is not propagated to the Data Source definition on the Catalog table. Is the report definition stored elsewhere?